# embedFonts complains about “Unknown device: pswrite”

Tags: r, fonts, ghostscript, postscript, font-embedding

Running `embedFonts` on some EPS file I created, I get an error message:

```
> embedFonts("foo.ps")
Unknown device: pswrite
Unrecoverable error: undefined in .uninstallpagedevice
Operand stack:
    defaultdevice
Error in embedFonts("foo.ps") : 
  status 1 in running command 'gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -q -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sDEVICE=pswrite -sOutputFile=/tmp/Rtmp3Lv0dj/Rembed2cd86df573a1 '-sFONTPATH='  'foo.ps''
```

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because the device is called `ps2write` these days. Support for writing post script level 1 has been dropped. The next R release (we are currently at 3.1.0, so this might be about 3.2) will contain a fix. Quoting from the list of changes:

> `embedFonts()` now defaults to `format = "ps2write"` for `.ps` and `.eps` files. This is available in Ghostscript 9.x (since 2010) whereas the previous default, `format = "pswrite"`, was removed in 9.10.

So the quick fix is to manually pass `format = "ps2write"` to the `embedFonts` invocation.